# How much does function alignment actually matter on modern processors?

Tags: performance, assembly, alignment, x86-64

When I compile C code with a recent compiler on an amd64 or x86 system, functions are aligned to a multiple of 16 bytes. How much does this alignment actually matter on modern processors? Is there a huge performance penalty associated with calling an unaligned function?

### Benchmark

I ran the following microbenchmark (`call.S`):

```
// benchmarking performance penalty of function alignment.
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#ifndef SKIP
# error "SKIP undefined"
#endif

#define COUNT 1073741824

        .globl _start
        .type _start,@function
_start: mov $COUNT,%rcx
0:      call test
        dec %rcx
        jnz 0b
        mov $SYS_exit,%rax
        xor %edi,%edi
        syscall
        .size _start,.-_start

        .align 16
        .space SKIP
test:   nop
        rep
        ret
        .size test,.-test
```

with the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `seq 0 15` ; do
        echo SKIP=$i
        cc -c -DSKIP=$i call.S
        ld -o call call.o
        time -p ./call
done
```

On a CPU that identifies itself as *Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2760QM CPU @ 2.40GHz* according to `/proc/cpuinfo`. The offset didn't make a difference for me, the benchmark took constant 1.9 seconds to run.

On the other hand, on another system with a CPU that reports itself as a *Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU L 640 @ 2.13GHz*, the benchmark takes 6.3 seconds, except if you have a offset of 14 or 15, where the code takes 7.2 seconds. I think that's because the function starts to span multiple cache lines.

Comment: please define unaligned x86 instructions/addresses?  x86 is variable length instructions so you are almost always unaligned.  The whole architecture is based on dealing with unaligned instructions, most branch destinations are unaligned

Comment: @dwelch: gcc aligns the entry point of a function (i.e. its first instruction) to a multiple of 16 bytes.

Comment: @GJ. Consider it done.

Comment: It is a prefetcher optimization, not just functions but branch targets too.  Nothing you could test with a simple loop.

Comment: @HansPassant That's possible. I don't know how to benchmark for such things though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Cache alignment matters. You don't want bytes that you won't execute.

You would, at least, want to avoid fetching instructions before the first one you will execute. Since this is a micro-benchmark, you most likely don't see any difference, but imagine on a full program, if you have an extra cache-miss on a bunch of functions because the first byte wasn't aligned to a cache-line and you eventually had to fetch a new cache line for the last N bytes of the function (where N <= the number of bytes before the function that you cached but didn't use).

[Intel's optimization manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) says this:

> **3.4.1.5 Code Alignment**
>
> Careful arrangement of code can enhance cache and memory locality. Likely sequences of basic blocks should be laid out contiguously in memory. This may involve removing unlikely code, such as code to handle error conditions, from the sequence. See
>   Section 3.7, “Prefetching,” on optimizing the instruction prefetcher.
>
> **3-8 ￼Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 12. (M impact, H generality)** All branch targets should be 16- byte aligned.
>
> **Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 13. (M impact, H generality)** If the body of a conditional is not likely to be executed, it should be placed in another part of the program. If it is highly unlikely to be executed and code locality is an issue, it should be placed on a different code page.

It also helps in explaining why you don't notice any difference in your program. All the code gets cached once and never leaves the cache (modulo context-switches, of course).

Comment: Intel removed the advice to align all branch targets by 16 in May 2020; CPUs without uop caches are mostly irrelevant these days, and aligning by 32 would not be worth it inside functions; aligning by 16 for functions is generally still done by compilers and seems reasonable to me.  See also https://agner.org/optimize/.  Also, other related Q&As like [Why does loop alignment on 32 byte make code faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45298870)