# Does Skylake have Loop Stream Detector?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture

In Agner Fog’s [microarchitecture manual](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf#page=153), Skylake has a Loopback buffer, which I guess is the Loop Stream Detector based on the description.

> The processor has a loop buffer which simply recycles µops from the µop queue, which has
> 64 entries per thread. The loop buffer will rarely use all 64 entries of the queue, but small loops of up to 30 µops, or sometimes up to 40, will benefit from the loop buffer. The loop buffer gives a stable throughput of 4 µops per clock, regardless of instruction length for tiny loops, according to my measurements.

When I simulate Skylake using uiCA, the Loop Stream Detector does not work, but it does work on Ice Lake.

uiCA (Skylake):

```
┌───────────────────────┬────────┬───────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────┐
│ MITE   MS   DSB   LSD │ Issued │ Exec. │ Port 0   Port 1   Port 2   Port 3   Port 4   Port 5   Port 6   Port 7 │ Notes │
├───────────────────────┼────────┼───────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────┤
│              1        │   1    │   1   │                                                         1             │       │ sub ecx, 0x1
│                       │        │       │                                                                       │   M   │ jnz 0xfffffffffffffffd
├───────────────────────┼────────┼───────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────┤
│              1        │   1    │   1   │                                                         1             │       │ Total
└───────────────────────┴────────┴───────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────┘
```

uiCA (Ice Lake)

```
┌───────────────────────┬────────┬───────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────┐
│ MITE   MS   DSB   LSD │ Issued │ Exec. │ Port 0   Port 1   Port 2   Port 3   Port 4   Port 5   Port 6   Port 7   Port 8   Port 9 │ Notes │
├───────────────────────┼────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────┤
│                    1  │   1    │   1   │  0.5                                                   0.5                              │       │ sub ecx, 0x1
│                       │        │       │                                                                                         │   M   │ jnz 0xfffffffffffffffd
├───────────────────────┼────────┼───────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────┤
│                    1  │   1    │   1   │  0.5                                                   0.5                              │       │ Total
└───────────────────────┴────────┴───────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────┘
```

Does Skylake have Loop Stream Detector?

Comment: ps. added a note about LSD efficiency: it's not always 4 uops per clock, unfortunately.  (I don't know if Ice Lake improved this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Skylake microcode update several years ago disabled the LSD to fix a correctness problem involving a corner case of AH-merging uops, erratum  Erratum SKL150.  Agner Fog's stuff was correct when he wrote it, but hasn't been updated with that or the JCC erratum.

- [Why jnz requires 2 cycles to complete in an inner loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156499/why-jnz-requires-2-cycles-to-complete-in-an-inner-loop/54263781#54263781)
- [Why does loop alignment on 32 byte make code faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298870/why-does-loop-alignment-on-32-byte-make-code-faster)
- [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256646/how-can-i-mitigate-the-impact-of-the-intel-jcc-erratum-on-gcc) (it sometimes leads to MITE legacy decode instead of the DSB)
- [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to) had some performance experiments from before the erratum.

---

> The loop buffer gives a stable throughput of 4 µops per clock, regardless of instruction length for tiny loops, according to my measurements.

On Sandybridge, a 5 uop loop could only issue at 2 cycles per iter, not 1.25, apparently with no issue group containing uops from multiple iterations.  *[Is performance reduced when executing loops whose uop count is not a multiple of processor width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311872/is-performance-reduced-when-executing-loops-whose-uop-count-is-not-a-multiple-of)* shows that's much less of a problem on later CPUs, with BeeOnRope's measurements for Haswell and Skylake (before microcode disabled its LSD).  But it still exists, with a worst-case throughput loss of 12.5% for a 7-uop loop on Haswell and old-microcode-Skylake.  (We think the LSD locks down 2 copies of the loop uops for small loops that fit twice.  14/4 = 3.5 cycles ideal, thus actual = 4.0 from the same effect happening across "unrolled" iterations.  3.5/4.0 is 0.875 efficiency = 1 minus 0.125)

Ice Lake's pipeline width is 5, Alder Lake P-core (Golden Cove) is 6.  I don't know if they improved the LSD any, like letting tiny loops "unroll" more copies.